# how can i get an object from one if condition to another if condition in java?

Tags: java

I'm a beginner. In the below program i want to use display methods in an `if` condition by using the object which i created in another `if` condition. Is there any possible way?

```
package emp;    
import java.util.*;
import emp.*;
public abstract class EmpMain2
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {   Class cl=new Class();
        System.out.println("1:Create");
        System.out.println("2:Display");
        System.out.println("3:Raisesalary");
        System.out.println("4:Exit");
        System.out.println("-------------------");
        System.out.println("Enter choice:");
        Scanner s1=new Scanner(System.in);
        int i=s1.nextInt();
        System.out.println("-------------------");
        if(i==1)
        {
            System.out.println("1:Clerk");
            System.out.println("2:Programmer");
            System.out.println("3:Manager");
            System.out.println("4:Exit");
            System.out.println("-------------------");
            System.out.println("Enter Choice:");
            Scanner s2=new Scanner(System.in);
            int j=s2.nextInt();
            System.out.println("-------------------");
            if(j==1)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter Name:");
                Scanner s3=new Scanner(System.in);
                String str1=s3.next();
                System.out.println("Enter age:");
                Scanner s4=new Scanner(System.in);
                int i1=s4.nextInt();            
                Cleark c1=new Cleark(str1,i1);
                System.out.println("Do u want go to main menu again:");
                System.out.println("If yes press 1:");
                Scanner s10=new Scanner(System.in);
                int l=s10.nextInt();
                if(l==1)
                {
                    main(args);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
            if(j==2)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter Name:");
                Scanner s5=new Scanner(System.in);
                String str2=s5.next();
                System.out.println("Enter age:");
                Scanner s6=new Scanner(System.in);
                int i2=s6.nextInt();
                Programer p1=new Programer(str2,i2);
                System.out.println("Do u want go to main menu again:");
                System.out.println("If yes press 1:");
                Scanner s11=new Scanner(System.in);
                int l=s11.nextInt();
                if(l==1)
                {
                    main(args);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.exit(0);
                }           
            }
            if(j==3)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter Name:");
                Scanner s7=new Scanner(System.in);
                String str3=s7.next();
                System.out.println("Enter age:");
                Scanner s8=new Scanner(System.in);
                int i3=s8.nextInt();            
                Manager m1=new Manager(str3,i3);
                System.out.println("Do u want go to main menu again:");
                System.out.println("If yes press 1:");
                Scanner s12=new Scanner(System.in);
                int l=s12.nextInt();
                if(l==1)
                {
                    main(args);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
            if(j==4)
            {   System.out.println();   
                main(args);
            }
        }
        if(i==2)
        {
            System.out.println("---------------------");
            //i want to use c1,m1 and p1 objects here
            System.out.println("---------------------");
        }
        if(i==3)
        {   System.out.println("----------------------");
            //i want to use c1,m1 and p1 objects here
            System.out.println("----------------------");
        }
        if(i==4)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }   


        System.out.println(Emp2.inc);

    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be constructing new `Scanner` objects. Write `final Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)` on the first lines and just use it throughout the code.

Comment: I know you are a beginner and all, but you really should look into how Finite State Machines work, rather than recursively call the main function to reach the initial state, because that is **really bad** practice.

Comment: If you want to use the variable c1,m1,p1 just expand their scope and please optimize your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can globally declare the reference and then create object whenever you want and then point that created object with that global reference that you created early.
for eg:

```
class Abc
 {
   Scanner s; //creating global reference of type Scanner
   if(//someCondition)
     {
       s = new Scanner(System.in); //creating new object of type Scanner and pointing it to reference s
     }
   if(//someOtherCondition)
    {
      String str = s.next(); // using that reference in another block
    }
 }
```

i think that you understand that if not please comment without hesitation and if it is your answer then mark it as answered so that it no longer remain in the category of unanswered.

Answer (score 2):

To access a variable, the variable must be in the same scope (i.e. in the same block delimited by curly braces), or in a block of a larger scope (i.e. in a block containing the current block):

```
{
    int i = 1;

    // i can be used here

    {
        // i can be used here
    }
}
// but i can not be used here
{
    // and i can't be used here either
}
```

So no, that's not possible with your current code. The variables would have to be declared in an outer block.

But even if they were, since they're initialized in a block that is executed if `i==1`, and you want to use them in a block that is executed if `i==2`, I don't see how you could use them. i can't be equal to 1 and 2 at the same time.

Finally, a note on your code: choose meaningful variable names. Use real words which describe what your variable represents. i, c1, m1, p1 don't mean anything and make your code unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using separated `ifs` you should use switch case:

```
  switch(i){
   case 1:
      <codes>
      break;
   case 2:
      <codes>
      break;
   .
   .
   .
   default:
     <codes>

  }
```

Also, you have to define objects out of `switch` to access inside of cases

Comment: elaborate please? it will not help the user.